# For which purposes LinkedIn uses Kafka

Tags: linkedin-api, apache-kafka, stream-processing, apache-samza

Can anyone tell me for which specific purposes LinkedIn uses Kafka. I read quite many articles from linkedin blog about Kafka. Where they explain how they use Kafka and how much performance benefit they have achieved.

Does Linkedin uses Kafka to notify other users in the network that your friend xxx have a new status update. Something like that

Answer (score 2):

For a good overview not only of Kafka's usage at LinkedIn, but also its origin and motivation, read Jay Krep's [The Log: What every software engineer should know about real-time data's unifying abstraction](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying).  It's quite long but worth the time.

For a specific use case, you can read my write up of the [Call Graph Analysis pipeline](https://engineering.linkedin.com/samza/real-time-insights-linkedins-performance-using-apache-samza) based on Kafka and Samza.  Additionally, the Tools team wrote on how they consume the output of that job to [monitor site performance in near real time](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-service-call-graph/real-time-distributed-tracing-website-performance-and-efficiency).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10997589)

Comment: Well, you're certainly welcome to fill that in if you wish.  It is better to provide some actual help rather than sniping at other's answers.